# can't see timeline in final cut pro

Tags: macos, final-cut-pro, mojave

[image]

I was clicking lots of buttons in the toolbar to try to hide things I didn't need (browser, inspector, etc.: I wanted the preview window as large as possible to get more detail in a crop) but the timeline disappeared too.

I thought "great that means the preview window can be even bigger".

But now I can't get the timeline back.

In fact, both the browser and the timeline toolbar buttons are greyed-out:

[image]

How do I show the timeline again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, luckily I figured it out almost immediately after asking.

I pressed Command-Control-1 (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>) to show the browser, and for some reason that un-greyed the timeline button, so I clicked the timeline button to show it again.

Then I could even hide the browser again but the timeline stayed visible.